# Are there tags for specific dialects?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

[dialects](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects) says in its [wiki](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/dialects/info):

> Language and vocabulary differences between specific regions of Japan.
>   Mostly used with specific dialect tag(s).
>
> Applies to any question asking about differences in language between
>   specific regions of Japan or definitions of specific words found in
>   said region. This tag is usually used in conjunction with a tag
>   specifying which dialect(s) the question is about.

But I when I looked at the "Related tags" for dialects, there were no tags for specific dialects mentioned, and it listed even tags with only one question in both dialects and that tag.

Did there use to be tags for specific dialects, which have since been deleted? If so, should the dialects wiki be updated accordingly?

Comment: The linked "duplicate" and this question have opposing accepted answers.  Perhaps the questions should just be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start having a tag for each dialect, it is going to be a mess. What you consider as a single dialact differs among people. Someone might want to create a "Kansai dialect" tag, but others might want "Osaka dialact", "Kyoto dialect", "Kawachi dialect", and so on. Someone might create "Tohoku dialect", but some others might want "Akita dialect", "Hirosaki dialect" and so on. With all the different names for a certain dialect, it will not be much useful for searching for Questions related to a certain dialect. For this reason, I think it is not a good idea to create a dialect tag for each dialect you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

There is [kansai-ben](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kansai-ben) already, and there could be more eventually.

If there are enough questions related to a particular dialect, it makes sense to create a tag for it. Conversely, if there's only one question, having a tag isn't very helpful.

Since tags get deleted automatically after a while if they aren't used again, if you ask a question on a specific dialect it's fine to create a new tag for it.

For example, tags on the Kyoto and Osaka dialects currently don't exist because as far as I see there are no questions specific to those dialects yet. If you do ask a question specific to one, consider creating a tag (if you have enough reputation) and if it gets used by more questions, it will become permanent.

Having tags for specific dialects *is* useful, because many users who live in a particular region of Japan may want to search or follow questions on dialects they are familiar with.